# Wait for "git clone" to finish in bash

Tags: git, bash

I have a sequential script in which there is a git clone.  I would like to make sure that the actual git process is finished before executing the next step.
I tried

```
git clone https://github.example.com/Sample/Example.git & export PID=${!} | while [[ ( -d /proc/$PID ) && ( -z `grep zombie /proc/$PID/status` ) ]]; do sleep 1; done
```

and various other ways but could not manage how to wait until the actual git clone is done.  Any hint on this one please?

Comment: I don't understand; `git clone` won't exit until the clone is complete or an error occurs.

Comment: It does. It is part of a script what is called by cron and some of the scripts after "git clone" fail because the repo is incomplete. If there is just like "sleep 30" then those are successful. However, all I am after is to check that "git clone" is really finished. The issue does not happen when you run it from the command line, only when it is started by cron. Thanks for the negative anyways.

Comment: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @trojanfoe `git clone` is being run in the background.

Answer (score 13):

Problem here is the `&` in your call. This will force the git command to be executed in the background. Just use `;` or `&&` to seperate your commands.

e.g.
This will echo "cloned"  in any case. Even if "git clone" failed.

```
git clone https://github.example.com/Sample/Example.git; echo "cloned"
```

or:

This will echo "cloned" only if clone was sucessful.

```
git clone https://github.example.com/Sample/Example.git && echo "cloned"
```

From you description I think you will need the second option.

Comment: P.S. `git clone https://github.example.com/Sample/Example.git && echo "cloned" || echo "clone failed"` will echo "clone failed" if it fails.

Comment: It does not work when the "git clone" command is invoked as part of a script by cron. What happens is that "git clone" runs async and it does not wait for a result.

Comment: What actually happens is that there are 3 detached processes spawned by git called as "git-remote-https" and those download the content. So the problem is a little more complicated. OFC, there might be other git commands running at the same time so ps axu or similar does not guarantee a good result when checked by just the name.

Comment: First of there should be no two git commands checking out in the same directory at the same time. If you can make sure that's the case there should be no problem with my suggested commands. You then can run as many git checkouts as you want, end each one will echo out "cloned" after success. Or do some more useful things :)

Answer (score 3):

The `&` sign forks the git process and puts it in the background. Replace it with `&&` or a newline if you want it to finish before continuing.

Comment: "The & sign forks the git process" .. What?!

Comment: True is that the shell forks itself and then exec's the git clone command, in background.